# How to navigate from UIViewClass to UIViewController Class using PushViewController method

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a button inside `UIView` class on the click of which i need to navigate to `UIViewController` class using  `NavigationViewController`.  I m stuck in this. Can anyone tell me the solution.
**Edit as per user comment**

```
-(void)eventDetailView:(id)sender
{ 
  EventDetailPage *eventDetail = [[EventDetailPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventDetailPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
  [[[[self window] rootViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:eventDetail animated:YES]; 
 }
```

Comment: -(void)eventDetailView:(id)sender{
    
        EventDetailPage *eventDetail = [[EventDetailPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventDetailPage" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [[[[self window] rootViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:eventDetail animated:YES];
}

Comment: post this code along with question

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this. It Works very well for me:-

Firstly Create Object of AppDelegate in UIView Class and initialize it.
Then create Navigationcontroller object in Appdelegate.h :-

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navControl;
```

In your UIView Class implement this code where you want to push :-

```
ViewController *objview = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [appDelegate.navControl pushViewController:objview animated:YES];
```